# Create dashboard using aws billing details on kibana dashboard hosted on aws elasticsearch service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, dashboard, kibana-6, aws-billing

Has anyone imported AWS billing details to aws kibana dashboard?

Tried to add custom plugins in aws elasticsearch for kibana but did not found option to add plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked, AWS ES service does not support custom plugins. Might be worth contacting AWS to see if this has changed.